# @Schedule Cron expression adjustment according to Day light saving from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I want to schedule two task which will run everyday at 1.01 AM CST/CEST (as server is on BST --> 00:01) and & 17.30 CST/CEST (So BST --> 16.30).

Because of day light saving time changes I have to adjust is manually. I want it to adjust automatically.

So how can I handle it in cron job

First task

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.schedule}") // 00:01
    public void startSchedulePullData() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Fetching all schedules");
        List<FileForTransfer> dataPullSchedulesList = dbUtils.findPullDataScheduled();
```

Second task

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.schedule.fileransfer}") // evening 5:30 PM CET
    public void startScheduleFileTransfer() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Fetching all schedules");
        List<FileForTransfer> fileTransferScheduleList = dbUtils.findFileTransferScheduled();
```

In properties file

```
job.schedule=0 01 00 * * *
job.schedule.fileransfer = 0 30 16 * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

During daylight saving changes, time should be updated at the server/machine where your code is running and it will be automatically reflected in your code without any manual adjustment.

If you feel this doesn't answer your question, please elaborate a bit more on the specific scenario and the adjustment you have to manually make.

Comment: Exactly I thought but few days ago time has changed according to daylight saving and Server is on BST but it didn't work properly.

Comment: When you say it didn't work properly, what was the exact issue?

Comment: Please go through my updated summary.

In case of second task previously (before Nov_2019)

"job.schedule.fileransfer = 0 30 15 * * * "

its was running as expected (17.30) .

but after daylight saving adjustment (after Nov_2019)  there is difference of 1 hour. So I made changes.

"job.schedule.fileransfer = 0 30 16 * * * "

Comment: Are you sure, timezone on the server is correct and the day light saving was implemented in the server running the code?

Comment: Yes I am Sure. Even I faced this issue again during this DST change

Comment: So, your server has switched from CEST to BST due to daylight savings but you still want to trigger cron in CEST.? Unfortunately, cron doesn't support timezones but you can fire cron every hour and check in code if it is the right time to trigger (not a clean solution). Or if your server is running on linux, you can set a cron timezone somthing like https://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/how-do-you-set-the-timezone-for-crontab